Trading view Pinescript : How to Label Green and Red Candles with Identical Opening Prices Separately in Pine Script?
I'm developing a Pine Script indicator where I aim to label green candles with identical opening prices separately from red candles with the same opening prices. Specifically, I want to label green candles with matching opening prices only with other green candles, and similarly, I want to label red candles with matching opening prices only with other red candles.
from the script below, my effort so far rather merges both green and red candles with same open price. What I want to achieve is to identify same green open and same red opens separately.
//@version=4
study("Identify Same Open Price Candles", overlay=true)

//calculate open price
openPrice = open

//identify green candles with same open price
greenCandles = openPrice == openPrice[1] and close > open

//identify red candles with same open price
redCandles = openPrice == openPrice[1] and close < open

//plot green and red candles with same open price
plotshape(greenCandles, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
plotshape(redCandles, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.small)

How can I modify this script to label red candles with identical opening prices, matching them only with other red candles? I want to ensure that green candles are labeled separately from red candles based on their opening prices.
